# Orfeo toolbox in Qgis fails to execute

Tags: orfeo-toolbox

I installed Orfeo using OSGeo4W and have set paths in QGIS (Wein) at

```
Processing -> Options & Configuration -> Providers -> Orfeo Toolbox
```

to:

Applications: `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\orfeotoolbox\applications`

Command line: `C:\OSGeo4W\bin`

And the contents of these folders include the required files.

When I try to run a command I get an immediate error:

> otbApplicationLauncherCommandLine.exe has stopped working

The log shows no errors and appears to have executed.

I wonder if I'm missing an installation step. I can't see Orfeo in the plugins menu for example. I'm running Windows 8.1, and used 64 bit OSGeo4W installer.

Comment: Could you open a bug on otb bug tracker or on OSGEO4W? https://bugs.orfeo-toolbox.org/my_view_page.php

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/84043)